# eBay OAuth invalid_grant when trying to get access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, ebay-api

I'm currently trying to get a small app to authenticate my own user.

First I navigate to

```
https://auth.ebay.com/oauth2/authorize?
  client_id=...&
  response_type=code&
  redirect_uri=...&
  scope=...
```

Which asks me to log in then gives me an authorization code via the url.

I url decode this and use postman to request the access token by hitting:

```
https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token
```

with Headers:

```
Authorization: Basic ...
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

These both appear to be correct, since if I change either of them I get an error saying that they're wrong.

And in the body:

```
grant_type: authorization_code
redirect_uri: ...
code: ...
```

Once again these all error individually if I change them to something else.

The error that I get is:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "the provided authorization grant code is invalid or was issued to another client"
}
```

Which is very strange to me. This is using the same redirect_uri and client_id as the previous request.

I've tried generating a new redirect url, I've tried rotating the client secret, I've tried not url decoding the auth code, but whatever I try I get the same error.

Interestingly, if I request a grant_type of client_credentials that works perfectly, but is of little use to me.

I'm very confused and the ebay forums are no help whatsoever, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Additional: I'm making these requests quite quickly, I'm aware that there's a quick timeout on the authorization code. Also, for the initial request I've tried using the sample link generated in the User Tokens page.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually managed to fix this myself.

I was url decoding the code using js's decodeURI, which was not actually decoding anything. Switched over to decodeURIComponent and now it seems to work ok